# Grafana Snapshot.raintank.io Sharing

Tags: grafana

I am a newbie with Grafana and I am trying to share my panel live.
I found the official doc which is well explained: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/share_panel/

However, I am having an issue with my snapshot.raintank.io. I generated a link by going to share --> Snapshot--> Publish to snapshot.raintank.io. In the expire box I filled to "Never". However, when I should have data coming live on my real panel, it is not coming live to my shared panel on snapshot.raintank.io.

So, is it normal that the snapshot.raintank.io is not going live but it is only a way to interact with the existing data or am I doing something wrong?

Let me know if you need any extra information.
Please help if you have any ideas :)

My html code:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
<iframe src="https://snapshot.raintank.io/dashboard/snapshot/*********?viewPanel=4&orgId=2&refresh=5s" width="1000" height="350" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://snapshot.raintank.io/dashboard/snapshot/*********??viewPanel=2&orgId=2&refresh=5s" width="1000" height="350" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Publishing a snapshot does just that: it publishes a *snapshot*. Snapshots are point-in-time captures of the data. They are captured just like you would take a snapshot of any other data store. They do not include any new or live updated information. If you want to publish your dashboard online then you will need to provide access to the dashboard directly.